# It is possible to handle a parametric variable in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi everyone I'm not an expert programmer but I'm trying to  optimize a vba code.
If I have variables decleared like: x1, x2, x3 ... and to eachone is associeted a value, is it possible to have something like:

```
Dim x1, x2
x1="Hello"
x2="world" 

For i=1 to n 
debug.print xi
next
```

Thanks for any Help

Comment: Have you looked into using an `Array` instead?

Comment: Yes I did, in fact my intention is to fill an array by means a For cycle. Anyway I found out a solution (see below)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim x(1 To 2) As String
    x(1) = "hello"
    x(2) = "world"
    For i = 1 To 2
        Debug.Print x(i)
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code you passed me but my compiler (a kind of vbs) doesn't accept it. It works like a charm on VBA.

Comment: I don't understand but my compiler seems doesn't accept a declaration like x(1).

Comment: @LorenzoD'Eleuterio My code works for *Excel365/VBA/Windows 10* have not tested it in another environment

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the problem, I tried eval() function and it worked:

```
Dim x1, x2
x1=9
x2=19
For i=1 To 2
  PoiSendMessage 1,  Eval("x" & i) , 1
Next
```